# Table works for one page, but not for multiple

Tags: errors, longtable

I have a `longtable`, that is inputted to the main-file using `LTXTable`, but it does not work, when the `longtable` is more than one page long.
The latex-code for the table can be found here: http://latex.lsm-consult.dk/longtable.tex
The main latex-code can be found here http://latex.lsm-consult.dk/timereg.tex
The other latex-files can be found at http://latex.lsm-consult.dk/auto1.tex and http://latex.lsm-consult.dk/payinfo.tex
And the payinfo.tex refered to in the error-output can be replaced by an empty file.
And the errors are

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `LastPage' on page 1 undefined on input line 49.

(./includes/latex/payinfo.tex (includes/latex/inv8578445//auto0.tex
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> \endtemplate 

l.3 \footnotesize
                  NR. \rule{0pt}{15pt}\rule[-10pt]{0pt}{0pt}        & \footnotesize...

?
! Emergency stop.
<template> \endtemplate 

l.3 \footnotesize
                  NR. \rule{0pt}{15pt}\rule[-10pt]{0pt}{0pt}        & \footnotesize...

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on includes/latex/inv8578445//timereg.log.
```

Can anybody in here give me a clue of what I am doing wrong?
I can of course also put the main file on my page, if you need it

Comment: Please provide a  full minimal example, i.e. a file that is compilable. What is the Y column specifier in this case? The error means that somewhere you have too many &'s, wrapping a preamble around it and changing Y to l, and it compiles fine. So please provide a bit more information.

Comment: @daleif Now I have provided a full minimal example in my question. You can also find, what Y means in the main-file. I can not find the place, where I have to many &'s, too less columns or forgotten a \\

Comment: @The87Boy: using the code you linked to I can compile without errors (after commenting out the line that loads the `uarial` package, which I don't have installed).

Comment: Interesting, I started having your error, then I downloaded everything again, and it went away.  Only thing I did was to insert the longtable.tex name in the \LTXtable command

Comment: Do you have 2 pages or more? If you only have 1, could you then try to add some pages, as I then have removed too much information from the main-page

Comment: @The87Boy: I just did a test adding text (up to 25 pages) with the `lipsum` package and still couldn't reproduce your error. Please provide a proper minimal example allowing us to reproduce the odd behaviour.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina Now I have updated the main page, I hope this help to get the odd behaviour

Comment: @The87Boy: I did a test using the files `timereg.tex`, `longtable.tex`, `auto1.tex`, and `payinfo.tex` that you provided and I couldn't reproduce the error. The document compiled with 0 errors in my system. Do you get the error mentioned compiling just those same 4 files? If so, maybe your LaTeX installation has some outdated package(s).

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina I do not get the error, when I just compile it, but when I add some more rows to the longtable it "arrives". It do not arrive, if I comment the header- and footer-section

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina I found the problem, which the payinfo.tex, that have to be a tabular instead of a tabularx. I do not know why, but it fixed this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.`

you have defined too less columns for the table or forgotton a `\\` at a tabular line end.

Comment: I can not find the place, where I have to many cells or forgotten a \\

Comment: the above links with your code works well for me.

Comment: @Herbert That sounds strange. Do it output more than one page? If it only output one page, could you then try to add some more rows, so it generates 2 pages or more?

Comment: Several pages when I add more rows, though the vertical lines does not match up

Comment: @The87Boy: makes no difference. Everything is fine. I have up-to-date TeXLive 2010

Comment: @daleif But you can compile, even if you have rows enough for multiple pages :o Because I can not :s

Comment: @Herbert That is strange due to my error

Comment: @The87Boy: start at the end of the longtable and comment every line out until the error went away.

Comment: @Herbert I will try that tomorrow, and if it does not work, I will come back tomorrow

Comment: @Herbert I have updated the files, I hope you can get the error now, so you can see, what is wrong

Comment: @The87Boy: what happens when you comment the `\onehalfspacing` out?

Comment: @Herbert That did not do the trick :( I still get the error but still only if I add too many rows, so I should go to the next page. But it works, if I coomment the header- and footer-sections

Comment: @The87Boy: from my point of view it is a  problem with one of the packages. Please comment out step by step any additional package except longtable and colortbl.

Comment: @Herbert It does not occur, when I comment fancyhdr and it's properties out, but I need fancyhdr :s It is \cfoot{\input{payinfo.tex}}, but I can not see why

Comment: @The87Boy: I'll come back to it at afternoon. Now my students are waiting ... :-) . You can try putting the contents directly into `\cfoot{...}` and not using \input

Comment: @Herbert I tried to change the payinfo.tex to tabular instead of tabularx, which worked, but unfortunately I can not make it fit the whole footer :(

Comment: @The87Boy: ok, I got it. Do not use a tabularx in `payinfo.tex`. Use a default `tabular` with `p` columns, if needed.

Comment: @Herbert Thanks, I have not seen p columns before now